# Map two dataframe base on a column and create a new column. Also match partial matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace

I have two dataframe

One with codes and values need to map to other dataframe

```py
B = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e','b','b','c'],
                  'Value': ["House with indoor pool", "House with Gray_C_Door", "Big Chandelier",
                            "Window Glass", "Frame Window",'High Column','Wood Raling', 'Window Glass trim']})
```

Other datframe content lots of data with values and need to make a new column base on dataframe "B" column "Code".

```py
A = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [2,34,12,45,np.nan,34,56,23,56,87,23,67,89,123,np.nan],
                  'Name': [ "House with indoor pool","House with Gray_C_Door",'House with indoor pool and Porch',"Wood Raling",
                           'Window Glass Tinted',"Windows Glass_with",'Big Chandelier', "Frame Window",np.nan,"Window glass","House with indoor pool",'High column with',
                           "Window Glass trim",'Frame Window',"glass Window"],
                 'Value': ["50", "100", "70", "20", "15",'75','50',"10", "10", "34", "5", "56",'12','83',np.nan]})
A.loc[:,'NewName'] = A['Name']
```

So I'm using the below code to replace A['NewName'].

```
A['NewName']= A['NewName'].replace(B.set_index('Value')['Code'])

    Test    Name                                Value   NewName
0   2.0000  House with indoor pool              50      a
1   34.0000 House with Gray_C_Door              100     b
2   12.0000 House with indoor pool and Porch    70      House with indoor pool and Porch
3   45.0000 Wood Raling                         20      b
4   NaN     Window Glass Tinted                 15      Window Glass Tinted
5   34.0000 Windows Glass_with                  75      Windows Glass_with
6   56.0000 Big Chandelier                      50      c
7   23.0000 Frame Window                        10      e
8   56.0000 NaN                                 10      NaN
9   87.0000 Window glass                        34      Window glass
10  23.0000 House with indoor pool              5       a
11  67.0000 High column with                    56      High column with
12  89.0000 Window Glass trim                   12      c
13  123.000 Frame Window                        83      e
14  NaN     glass Window                        NaN     glass Window
```

However, some A['NewName'] are not matching with B['Value'] and doesn't give an exact expected outcome.

Is there a way, I can match those values when It has partial matching with A['NewName'] and give the correct code?
I mean for instance when A['NewName'] has "House with indoor pool and Porch" I want to match it with B['Value'] =  'House with indoor pool' and replace it with correct B['Code] = 'a'. I couldn't add that to the data frame B Values column because there are several ways it could change after "House with indoor pool" (for ex: "House with indoor pool_ with big glass door", "House with indoor pool and High railings" etc.)

Is this possible to do it in a map/replace function or any other method?

Thanks in advacne!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using `difflib`. We effectively do the outer product of comparisons of `Name` and `Value` for which there's no exact match, to find the best fit (according to `difflib`) before making a selection.

To flag really poor matches, we can set a threshold for the `difflib` match ratio below which we return NaN. I have selected 0.5 in the code below, which catches the sample input `Name` "I don't match anything".

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
B = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e','b','b','c'],
                  'Value': ["House with indoor pool", "House with Gray_C_Door", "Big Chandelier",
                            "Window Glass", "Frame Window",'High Column','Wood Raling', 'Window Glass trim']})
A = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [2,34,12,45,np.nan,34,56,23,56,87,23,67,89,123,np.nan,333],
                  'Name': [ "House with indoor pool","House with Gray_C_Door",'House with indoor pool and Porch',"Wood Raling",
                           'Window Glass Tinted',"Windows Glass_with",'Big Chandelier', "Frame Window",np.nan,"Window glass","House with indoor pool",'High column with',
                           "Window Glass trim",'Frame Window',"glass Window","I don't match anything"],
                 'Value': ["50", "100", "70", "20", "15",'75','50',"10", "10", "34", "5", "56",'12','83',np.nan,'999']})

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
bValues = B['Value'].to_list()
bValuesDict = {value : idx for idx, value in enumerate(bValues)}
columnCode = B.columns.to_list().index('Code')
def getCode(x):
    name = x['Name']
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        return np.nan
    if name in bValuesDict: 
        idx = bValuesDict[name]
    else:
        bMatches = [SequenceMatcher(None, name, value).ratio() for value in bValues]
        maxRatio = max(bMatches)
        if maxRatio < 0.5:
            return np.nan
        idx = bMatches.index(maxRatio)
    code = B.iloc[idx, columnCode]
    return code
A['NewName'] = A.apply(getCode, axis=1)

print(A)
```

Output:

```
     Test                              Name Value NewName
0     2.0            House with indoor pool    50       a
1    34.0            House with Gray_C_Door   100       b
2    12.0  House with indoor pool and Porch    70       a
3    45.0                       Wood Raling    20       b
4     NaN               Window Glass Tinted    15       c
5    34.0                Windows Glass_with    75       a
6    56.0                    Big Chandelier    50       c
7    23.0                      Frame Window    10       e
8    56.0                               NaN    10     NaN
9    87.0                      Window glass    34       a
10   23.0            House with indoor pool     5       a
11   67.0                  High column with    56       b
12   89.0                 Window Glass trim    12       c
13  123.0                      Frame Window    83       e
14    NaN                      glass Window   NaN       e
15  333.0            I don't match anything   999     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` (regular expression) in your own function and apply this function to `A['Name']` (btw initializing 'Newname' is useless here):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

B = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e','b','b','c'],
                  'Value': ["House with indoor pool", "House with Gray_C_Door", "Big Chandelier",
                            "Window Glass", "Frame Window",'High Column','Wood Raling', 'Window Glass trim']})

A = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [2,34,12,45,np.nan,34,56,23,56,87,23,67,89,123,np.nan],
                  'Name': [ "House with indoor pool","House with Gray_C_Door",'House with indoor pool and Porch',"Wood Raling",
                           'Window Glass Tinted',"Windows Glass_with",'Big Chandelier', "Frame Window",np.nan,"Window glass","House with indoor pool",'High column with',
                           "Window Glass trim",'Frame Window',"glass Window"],
                 'Value': ["50", "100", "70", "20", "15",'75','50',"10", "10", "34", "5", "56",'12','83',np.nan]})

B_series = B.set_index('Value')

def get_code_for_matching_value(val):
    if type(val)==str:
        if val in B_series.index:
            return B_series.at[val, 'Code']
        else:
            for i in B_series.index:
                if re.match(i, val):
                    return B_series.at[i, 'Code']
    return val
        
A['NewName']= A['Name'].apply(get_code_for_matching_value)
print(A)
```

Output:

```
     Test                              Name Value             NewName
0     2.0            House with indoor pool    50                   a
1    34.0            House with Gray_C_Door   100                   b
2    12.0  House with indoor pool and Porch    70                   a
3    45.0                       Wood Raling    20                   b
4     NaN               Window Glass Tinted    15                   a
5    34.0                Windows Glass_with    75  Windows Glass_with
6    56.0                    Big Chandelier    50                   c
7    23.0                      Frame Window    10                   e
8    56.0                               NaN    10                 NaN
9    87.0                      Window glass    34        Window glass
10   23.0            House with indoor pool     5                   a
11   67.0                  High column with    56    High column with
12   89.0                 Window Glass trim    12                   c
13  123.0                      Frame Window    83                   e
14    NaN                      glass Window   NaN        glass Window
```

Note: you can improve matching by making it case insensitive (for example): `if re.match(i.lower(), val.lower()):`